# Python - Should I put my helper functions inside or outside the class?

Tags: python, class, pylint

In Python, if some methods of a class need a helper function, but the helper function itself doesn't use anything in the class, should I put the helper function inside or outside the class?

I tried putting it inside but PyLint was complaining that this function could have been put outside.

@Karl:

The class is a software upgrader and the helper function creates a new folder if the folder doesn't exist yet. The class is in a module having pretty much only the code for the class as of now. Other classes may be added later on.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `@staticmethod` decorator?

Comment: I wasn't but now I am. :) Thanks!

Comment: `@staticmethod` should not be used to replace module-level methods. Don't code java in python.

Comment: There are surprisingly few generalities in programming. Tell us more about your class and your helper function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: More details added. Thanks!

Comment: @Falmarri: if that function is related to the class (but don't need any of its data), and more classes might be added later which have nothing to do with that function, I think the OP has a very legit use-case for `@staticmethod`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When deciding where to put helper functions the question I ask is, "Is it only for this class?"  If it can help in other places, then it goes at the module level; if it is indeed only for this class, then it goes in the class with either `staticmethod` (needs no class data to do its job) or `classmethod` (uses some class, but not instance, data to do its job).

Another python code checker is [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes).

Answer (score 11):

It's possible that the helper function better fits in at the module level rather than the class.

If you don't agree that this is the case, there is a [staticmethod decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) that you can use on functions inside of the class. Simply put, a static method behaves the same between object instantiations of the same class. It does not rely on instance data.

For this reason, the `staticmethod` decorator renders behavior on the function such that it does not take an implicit first argument (typically `self`) as stated in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks! My stuff doesn't fit well at the module level. I'm gonna go with the func decorator. Thanks again for your help! - Jack

Comment: I don't know if this will stop the PyLint warning. I haven't used PyLint, but when the Python documentation recommends something, it's probably good enough.

Comment: cool :) A side question though, if you don't use PyLint, what do you usually use to check the code? Thanks!

Comment: @JackZ: PyDev perhaps? It's *the* python plugin for the Eclipse IDE. And it also has an option to use PyLint on top of it's buit-in checker.